# Possible to pass a '&str' or '&String' to function in Rust using 'Into'?

Tags: rust

In Rust a function may take an `Into<String>`:

```
fn get_by_key<S: Into<String>>(&self, key: S) -> Option<&Value>;
```

Is it possible to pass in a reference to string, so there is no need to clone a `String` when passing it into the function (using something like `Into<&String>>`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply make your function accept `&str`, and then pass an `&String` will work by implicitly de-referencing it.

See [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html).

```
fn main() {
    fn get_by_key(_key: &str) {}

    let s1: &str = "foo";
    let s2: String = "foo".into();

    get_by_key(s1);
    get_by_key(&s2);
}
```